# a-frame a-tube animating extra primitives

Tags: animation, three.js, aframe

trying to animate a-tube https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras by addressing the the path;

```
          <a-tube path="-1.8 -0.5 0, 0 0.75 0" radius="0.1" 
              animation="property: tube.path; from: -1.8 -0.5 0, 0 0.75 0; to: -1.8 -0.5 -1, 0 0.75 0; dur: 2000; easing: linear; loop: true; dir: alternate"></a-tube>
```

I've tried quite a few iterations and none seem to work, this is where I'm at now. My understanding was that it not being a native primitive shouldn't be the issue but the scope for me being wrong is quite grand.

I've gone through the documentation for a-frame animations for some time and it hasn't really illuminated me.

Can you animate a-tube path property in the without rewriting the entire thing?

Comment: What's the issue, Your code seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/ah7yfc0m/

Comment: Well that's just worked. Oh god I've gone down a deep dark rabbit hole for the day. Oh well, I guess I learned something. Feeling great about my upcoming interview.

Thanks for your help. I would've been going mad without you

Comment: So using src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-extras@3.3.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js" doesn't work but using src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js" will. Something about Don McUrdys works that doesn't on unpkg.

Answer (score 0):

Using `src="unpkg.com/aframe-extras@3.3.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"` doesn't work but using `src="cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/…"` will. Something about Don McUrdys works that doesn't on unpkg.

If you're discovering this confused that's your issue.